# Print variable above

Tags: php

Not the best name for a thread but still...

I got

```
<?php include('inc/nav_bar.php'); ?>
...
<?php
    main code block
?>
```

I need to print one variable from "main code block" to "nav_bar" block,
is there is any good way to do this ?

The only solution I've found so far is to use javascript.

Comment: How about you have your content of nav_bar in a class, and you call that? Like navBar($mainBlockVariable)

Comment: You want to print out an variable from the lowest block in the block above with PHP..? That would be kinda impossible to do don't you think?

Comment: Might be interesting for you http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Comment: I think you can't. You can use function though!

Comment: Create a `function( $value ){ echo $value; }` in `nav_bar` and call that function from `main code block`

Comment: Don't work, function print $value at the place it was call from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly your nav_bar.php prints out something which should contain the value of a variable in the main code block.

Then you could try to "catch" the output of the nav_bar.php:

```
ob_start();
include('inc/nav_bar.php');
$navBarContent = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
// main code block: replace some placeholders in $navBarContent with variables content
```

Edit: But I agree with the others. A better solution is to change your code-design and use classes/functions.

Answer (score 0):

You may use different ways - rearrange code blocks or use output buffering.

Is 'nav_bar.php' echo any content? Try this:

```
{nav_bar.php}
...
echo "some text %VAR% some text";
...

{main.php}
ob_start();
include 'inc/nav_bar.php';
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$var = doSomeCalc();
$content = str_replace('%VAR%', $var, $content);

echo $content;
```

OR you may use this way:

```
{main.php}
$main_var = doSomeCalc();
...
include 'inc/nav_bar.php';
...
echo "something else";


{nav_bar.php}
...
echo "some text $main_var some text"; // use $main_var defined earlier
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's time for you to start using the **MVC pattern** in your applications :)

This will solve all your output priority problems.

Read more here :
["What is MVC ?"](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html#2)

Answer (score -1):

I'd go for this pattern:

```
<?php
// main code block

include('inc/nav_bar.php');
```

But if you want to go steps forward with your own skill and make your life easier, use templating (which takes an approach from the inside out, instead of the other way around).

Look up Twig or Smarty if you want to make use of some existing templating engine. I'd also highly recommend Zend Framework, which uses mainly purely PHP based templates (you could use other engines too) and Symfony (uses mainly Twig).